# Will the Starship skirt envelope heat during landing?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

Starship lands on the pad using the landing burn of 1-2 raptor engines. The landing legs offer little vertical clearance from the ground, whereas during lift off, the suborbital launch pad provides enough ground clearance. During landing, the heat from the landing burn can be enveloped by the Starship skirt and put the craft in danger. How far does this theory of mine hold true?

Comment: Do not have a source for starship but area around rocket engines is exhaust temperature as a matter of course and needs protection https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkObNfCki6M so expectation would be that everything in the skirt area would need insulation.

Comment: As you might well imagine, the SpaceX team is fully aware of the thermal profile (in 3D) during the landing maneuver and have designed the necessary thermal protection into the system.  Perhaps you should change your question to "How does Starship protect against heating effects during landing"

Comment: Your theory holds true in so far as there is a blast and thermal risk. SpaceX will have done the necessary calculations and simulations and taken precautionary measures via insulation and protection. The matter is a little easier as these are prototypes and are not expected to fly more than a very few times.